# VSCode autocompletion issues for Laravel packages

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I've a problem with autocompletion in VSCode: the text editor doesn't show me the suggestions for methods of the external packages.

In this case, i'm trying the Faker package but when I type `$faker->addr`, I cannot see the method `address()` in the autocompletion hints.

Do you know how to fix this problem? 
It's annoying, mostly when you're learning new stuff and the autocompletion helps a lot.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlUcZ.png) is an example what I intended.

Comment: My 1 cent, use PHPStorm.

Comment: Are you using the builtin PHP engine or some of the third-party extensions? How do you define `$faker`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm using some extensions for PHP like IntelliSense, PHP formattere et similar.
I've defined `$faker` in this way `$faker = Faker\Factory::create('it_IT');`

Comment: VSCode isn't an IDE it's an text editor. PHPStorm or Netbeans are IDEs.

Comment: @SuperDJ Yeah, you're right. My fault

Answer (score 0):

`Faker\Factory::create()` looks like this:

```
/**
 * Create a new generator
 *
 * @param string $locale
 * @return Generator
 */
public static function create($locale = self::DEFAULT_LOCALE)
{
    $generator = new Generator();
    foreach (static::$defaultProviders as $provider) {
        $providerClassName = self::getProviderClassname($provider, $locale);
        $generator->addProvider(new $providerClassName($generator));
    }

    return $generator;
}
```

That means that, unless you have a really cool static analysis engine, all the editor will see is a `Faker\Generator` instance. And such class does not have any `address()` method because it's a magic method.

However, the library uses annotations to describe magic *properties*:

```
/**
 * @property string $address
 */
```

That means that you can sensibly expect to get, at least, such property.

In my experience the [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) is slightly smarter than [PHP IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense). I can confirm you that, at least in this case, Intelephense actually suggests `$faker->address` as property, while IntelliSense doesn't.

---

*Out of curiosity, I tried PhpStorm with [fzaninotto/faker](https://packagist.org/packages/fzaninotto/faker) and it doesn't recognise the magic method either (not at least out of the box)—it does recognise it as magic property though.*

Comment: Thank you a lot, I've just installed Intelephense!
Btw in a class that I'm actually taking on Udemy, the instructor uses PHPStorm and it recognise the methods (maybe with some plugins).